# JDK 1.6 and servlet containers

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

When you upgrade to a newer version of the JDK (from 1.5 to 1.6), do you also have to reinstall your servlet container so it takes advantage of the new JDK?

The environment in question is running JBoss 4.0.5 with Java 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you are upgrading (going from 1.5 to 1.6) you don't have to reinstall your servlet container. Unless you are using a very specific library which totally depends on 1.5 to work (which is unlikely).

If you are going the opposite way and downgrading (going from 1.6 to 1.5) you might need a different version of the servlet container. But that would depend on the stuff you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't **have to**, but you **may do**. Just check if the features/enhancements provided by the newer JDK 1.6-only appservers, of which currently no one comes to mind by the way, they're all backwards compatible to at least JDK 1.5, are really beneficial in your case. If so, then upgrade.

But as you already may have guessed, there's no benefit as far as no one exist yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Its **Not Required**. Just check if any library or dependency is something that is very specifically supported to the older version ONLY(which is very unlikely). Otherwise its good! There would not be an problem, glad to know someone is exactly working on the same platform as me.